# Change from int PK to string PK

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

In my application I had all my `models` with `int Id` as `primary key`. Now I got at the point where I really need three of my `models` to have `string Id`. I changed the `Id` for all three to `string`, but after I create the `migration` and run `update-database`, I get an error. This is what I have now:
Project model:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("VendorId")]
    public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    public string VendorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AdministratorId")]
    public Administrator Administrator { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Administrator")]
    public string AdministratorId { get; set; }
}
```

Client model:

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Vendor model:

```
public class Vendor
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Administrator model:

```
public class Administrator
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

(to be mentioned that I removed unnecessary code)
This was working perfectly when `Vendor`, `Client` and `Administrator` models had `int Id`, but now, this is the error I get on an `update-database` command:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The constraint 'PK_dbo.Administrators' is being referenced by table 'Projects', foreign key constraint 'FK_dbo.Jobs_dbo.Administrators_AdministratorId'.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
ClientConnectionId:b67d4f49-f332-4897-a129-f10751ee40ed
Error Number:3725,State:0,Class:16
The constraint 'PK_dbo.Administrators' is being referenced by table 'Projects', foreign key constraint 'FK_dbo.Jobs_dbo.Administrators_AdministratorId'.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

**UPDATE** The migration code:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Projects","ClientId","dbo.Clients");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.InvoicePayables","AdministratorId","dbo.Administrators");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.InvoicePayables","VendorId","dbo.Vendors");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.InvoiceTakings","AdministratorId","dbo.Administrators");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.InvoiceTakings","ClientId","dbo.Clients");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Projects","AdministratorId","dbo.Administrators");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.ClientContactPersons","Client_Id","dbo.Clients");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Translations","Vendor_Id","dbo.Vendors");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Projects","VendorId","dbo.Vendors");
    DropIndex("dbo.ClientContactPersons",new[]{"Client_Id"});
    DropIndex("dbo.Projects",new[]{"VendorId"});
    DropIndex("dbo.Projects",new[]{"ClientId"});
    DropIndex("dbo.Projects",new[]{"AdministratorId"});
    DropIndex("dbo.InvoicePayables",new[]{"VendorId"});
    DropIndex("dbo.InvoicePayables",new[]{"AdministratorId"});
    DropIndex("dbo.Translations",new[]{"Vendor_Id"});
    DropIndex("dbo.InvoiceTakings",new[]{"ClientId"});
    DropIndex("dbo.InvoiceTakings",new[]{"AdministratorId"});
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Administrators");
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Clients");
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Vendors");
    AddColumn("dbo.InvoiceTakings","Administrator_Id",c=>c.String(maxLength:128));
    AddColumn("dbo.InvoiceTakings","Client_Id",c=>c.String(maxLength:128));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Administrators","Id",c=>c.String(nullable:false,maxLength:128));
    AlterColumn("dbo.ClientContactPersons","Client_Id",c=>c.String(maxLength:128));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Clients","Id",c=>c.String(nullable:false,maxLength:128));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Projects","VendorId",c=>c.String(maxLength:128));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Projects","ClientId",c=>c.String(maxLength:128));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Projects","AdministratorId",c=>c.String(maxLength:128));
    AlterColumn("dbo.InvoicePayables","VendorId",c=>c.String(maxLength:128));
    AlterColumn("dbo.InvoicePayables","AdministratorId",c=>c.String(maxLength:128));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Vendors","Id",c=>c.String(nullable:false,maxLength:128));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Translations","Vendor_Id",c=>c.String(maxLength:128));
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Administrators","Id");
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Clients","Id");
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Vendors","Id");
    CreateIndex("dbo.ClientContactPersons","Client_Id");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Projects","VendorId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Projects","ClientId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Projects","AdministratorId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.InvoicePayables","VendorId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.InvoicePayables","AdministratorId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Translations","Vendor_Id");
    CreateIndex("dbo.InvoiceTakings","Administrator_Id");
    CreateIndex("dbo.InvoiceTakings","Client_Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Projects","ClientId","dbo.Clients","Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.InvoicePayables","AdministratorId","dbo.Administrators","Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.InvoicePayables","VendorId","dbo.Vendors","Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.InvoiceTakings","Administrator_Id","dbo.Administrators","Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.InvoiceTakings","Client_Id","dbo.Clients","Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Projects","AdministratorId","dbo.Administrators","Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.ClientContactPersons","Client_Id","dbo.Clients","Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Translations","Vendor_Id","dbo.Vendors","Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Projects","VendorId","dbo.Vendors","Id");
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Projects","VendorId","dbo.Vendors");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Translations","Vendor_Id","dbo.Vendors");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.ClientContactPersons","Client_Id","dbo.Clients");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Projects","AdministratorId","dbo.Administrators");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.InvoiceTakings","Client_Id","dbo.Clients");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.InvoiceTakings","Administrator_Id","dbo.Administrators");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.InvoicePayables","VendorId","dbo.Vendors");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.InvoicePayables","AdministratorId","dbo.Administrators");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Projects","ClientId","dbo.Clients");
    DropIndex("dbo.InvoiceTakings",new[]{"Client_Id"});
    DropIndex("dbo.InvoiceTakings",new[]{"Administrator_Id"});
    DropIndex("dbo.Translations",new[]{"Vendor_Id"});
    DropIndex("dbo.InvoicePayables",new[]{"AdministratorId"});
    DropIndex("dbo.InvoicePayables",new[]{"VendorId"});
    DropIndex("dbo.Projects",new[]{"AdministratorId"});
    DropIndex("dbo.Projects",new[]{"ClientId"});
    DropIndex("dbo.Projects",new[]{"VendorId"});
    DropIndex("dbo.ClientContactPersons",new[]{"Client_Id"});
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Vendors");
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Clients");
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Administrators");
    AlterColumn("dbo.Translations","Vendor_Id",c=>c.Int());
    AlterColumn("dbo.Vendors","Id",c=>c.Int(nullable:false,identity:true));
    AlterColumn("dbo.InvoicePayables","AdministratorId",c=>c.Int(nullable:false));
    AlterColumn("dbo.InvoicePayables","VendorId",c=>c.Int(nullable:false));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Projects","AdministratorId",c=>c.Int());
    AlterColumn("dbo.Projects","ClientId",c=>c.Int(nullable:false));
    AlterColumn("dbo.Projects","VendorId",c=>c.Int());
    AlterColumn("dbo.Clients","Id",c=>c.Int(nullable:false,identity:true));
    AlterColumn("dbo.ClientContactPersons","Client_Id",c=>c.Int());
    AlterColumn("dbo.Administrators","Id",c=>c.Int(nullable:false,identity:true));
    DropColumn("dbo.InvoiceTakings","Client_Id");
    DropColumn("dbo.InvoiceTakings","Administrator_Id");
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Vendors","Id");
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Clients","Id");
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Administrators","Id");
    CreateIndex("dbo.InvoiceTakings","AdministratorId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.InvoiceTakings","ClientId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Translations","Vendor_Id");
    CreateIndex("dbo.InvoicePayables","AdministratorId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.InvoicePayables","VendorId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Projects","AdministratorId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Projects","ClientId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Projects","VendorId");
    CreateIndex("dbo.ClientContactPersons","Client_Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Projects","VendorId","dbo.Vendors","Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Translations","Vendor_Id","dbo.Vendors","Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.ClientContactPersons","Client_Id","dbo.Clients","Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Projects","AdministratorId","dbo.Administrators","Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.InvoiceTakings","ClientId","dbo.Clients","Id",cascadeDelete:true);
    AddForeignKey("dbo.InvoiceTakings","AdministratorId","dbo.Administrators","Id",cascadeDelete:true);
    AddForeignKey("dbo.InvoicePayables","VendorId","dbo.Vendors","Id",cascadeDelete:true);
    AddForeignKey("dbo.InvoicePayables","AdministratorId","dbo.Administrators","Id",cascadeDelete:true);
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Projects","ClientId","dbo.Clients","Id",cascadeDelete:true);
}
```

(Sorry for long code for the migration...it includes all other properties)
What am I missing?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why can't you just parse the int to a string?

Comment: What I want to do is to create vendors, clients and administrators with the ID that Identity set to them, which is string. (Client, Vendor and Administrator are also accounts)

Comment: An ugly solution would be to create a table that maps Identity string Id to my int Id, but I would really like to avoid this...

Comment: What does your migration look like?  Are you handling the change of data type in SQL correctly?

Comment: @Thewads I updated my post with the migration code.

Comment: It has been a good approach for me to do these kind of things in steps. Without looking at your code & error in full detail, you could try start by removing the foreign keys in question. Add that migration and update the database. And then move onto the next part of your change.

Comment: I am not certain as I am rusty on my EF Code first and migrations but you may be missing the setting to allow data loss: 'AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;'.  I remember when I was testing Migrations before it had issues when changing column names and values related to this.  I also think you would need to drop you foreign key constraints first, before a data change as they are generally forcing no change by their very existance and your error says something similar.

Comment: Is there any reason you could not rename the Id fields to something like ClientId, AdministrationId, VendorId versus reuse Id for all of them?  It's a good practice to name your Primary Key something that distinguishes it from other possible Foreign Keys.  Otherwise, you will have issues when joining those records and require aliases (which should be used regardless).  Just a thought there.  Also, why a string?  Strings are not really good for Primary Keys is why I ask, as well, they can't be Indexed.

Comment: @IyaTaisho I explained in the post...I want to have the same ID as the Identity gives to an account, which is a string.

Comment: @IyaTaisho Well, I took your advice and I left my Id's as int and just added another string property to my models, like 'ClientAccountId', 'VendorAccountId' and 'AdministratorAccountId', where i just save the identity Id. Thank you!

Comment: No worries.  Glad it helped.  Are you have any issues with it now?